# Partial View not rendering properly after ajax call success

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, partial-views

So on initial load the page loads fine with all data populated... Once i do my ajax call and bring the data back.. Instead of populating my partial view.. Its just populating the json to the div...

```
public JsonResult UpdateSerialNumber(string serialNumber)
        {

            string connectionstring = configuration.GetConnectionString("DataBase");
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))

            {
                string query = "Insert Into SerialNumbers (SerialNumber)" +
            "Values('" + serialNumber + "')";

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            string sql = "select * from SerialNumbers";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter();
            ad.SelectCommand = cmd;
            ad.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            SerialNumbers sNum = new SerialNumbers();
            string[] serialArray = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(k => k[1].ToString()).ToArray();

            List<SerialNumbers> serial = serialArray.Select(s => new SerialNumbers { SerialNumber = s }).ToList();

            SingleStageTerminal term = new SingleStageTerminal();
            term.SerialNumbers = serial;
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            //serialArray = js.Serialize(term.SerialNumbers);
            return Json(serialArray);
```

AJAX CALL

```
<script>
    
   
     self.url = '@Url.Action("UpdateSerialNumber")'
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Get value on button click and show alert
        $("#associate").click(function () {
            var str = $("#SerialTb").val();
        
            $.ajax(self.url,
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: ({ SerialNumber: str }),
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                     $("#serialPartial").html(data);
                 }
            })
        });
    });
  

</script>
```

PARTIAL VIEW CALL

```
<div id="serialPartial">
                                @{
                                    @Html.Partial("_PartialViewSerialNumbers", Model.SerialNumbers)
                                }

                            </div>
```

ACTUAL PARTIAL VIEW

```
<div class="card w-100">
    <h5 class="card-header"><b>Serial Numbers</b></h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card card-block user-card">
                <ul id="SerialNumbersTest" class="scroll-list cards">
                    @if (ViewBag.Serials == null)
                    {
                        @foreach (var item in Model.SerialNumbers)
                        {
                            <li>
                                <h6 style="text-align:center">@item</h6>
                            </li>
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Serials)
                        {
                            <li>
                                <h6 style="text-align:center">@item</h6>
                            </li>
                        }
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

before ajax success

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

AFTER ajax sucess

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

As you can see, the JSON is being populated into the DIV and its not actually going into my partial result.. can anyone help.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxP1L.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NLhI.png

Comment: This `$("#serialPartial").html(data);` line just put data which you have return from ajax to div `serialPartial`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Partial View Not Have any Model To Display and Don't have **ViewData** Your Pass Object But not Received on Partial View.

Also Partial View Have Your Layout may be its shows header so Add

> Layout = null

on top of page.

Here is your changes Step by Step

in UpdateSerialNumber Action

**From**

```
 public JsonResult UpdateSerialNumber(string serialNumber)
```

**To**

```
 public ActionResult UpdateSerialNumber(string serialNumber)
```

**Change Return Type From**

```
 return Json(serialArray);
```

**To**

```
 return View( "_PartialViewSerialNumbers" ,serialArray)
```

**Remove This Line Render Partial**

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialViewSerialNumbers", Model.SerialNumbers)
```

**Add This line On top of Partial View**

```
@model string[]
@{ 
   layout = null;
}
```

**Replace From**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.SerialNumbers)
```

**To**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```